# Becoming Bitcoin wallet provider from scratch

Tags: blockchain, wallet, private-key, public-key

I want to launch a bitcoin wallet service website for creating new wallets.

And i want to provide a tool for user for importing their old wallets using public and private key.

I know i can use some API's like `blockchain.info api` and some others

But they just allow to create wallets in their system , and you can not import other wallets using their api in your account.

How can i be a bitcoin wallet service provider from scratch?

i want to let my clients create new account with new wallet address + import and exporting wallets using public and private key + send & recieve money with other wallets + etc

- Please +1 question if you don't know too

Comment: There is a standard Wallet Import Format (WIF): https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#term-wallet-import-format utilized by the bitcoin core wallet with `importprivkey` and `dumpprivkey`

Comment: @JBaczuk thanks , do you know there any easier way or API? the document does not seem friendly for development.

Comment: what language are you coding in?

Comment: An API that lets you import private keys is very likely to be a scam.

Comment: @MCCCS, but what about https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#importprivkey ?

Comment: @JBaczuk php is my default

Comment: If you have to ask you shouldn't be doing it